# Why the css2sass and sass-convert converter trips off with CSS multiline comment?

Tags: compass-sass, sass

The CSS to convert to SASS:

```
body {
   background: transparent !important; color: #444 !important; text-shadow: none;
  }

  /* Don't show links for images */
  pre, blockquote {
   border: 1px solid #999; page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
  img {
   page-break-inside: avoid;
  }


/* Grade-A Mobile Browsers */
html {
   -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none;
  }
```

Converted SASS:

```
body
  background: transparent !important
  color: #444 !important
  text-shadow: none

/* Don't show links for images

pre, blockquote
  border: 1px solid #999
  page-break-inside: avoid

img
  page-break-inside: avoid

/* Grade-A Mobile Browsers

html
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none
  -ms-text-size-adjust: none
```

Watch out the `/* Don't show links for images` and `/* Grade-A Mobile Browsers`.

That makes the whole block after it commented.

It should have been `/* Don't show links for images */` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Sass can go both ways. You have to understand that for Sass, `/*` is just the starting point of a block comment that will go like this :

```
/* This is the beginning of a commment
    * This line is indented under it, so it's part of the comment

html
    // This selector is not indented so it's not part of the comment
```

Sass doesn't need `*/` to end comments the same way it doesn't need } to end selectors : the indentation takes care of it for you.

I recommand you check the Sass comments syntax in more detail in the [reference page](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#comments).

Answer (score -1):

sass-convert --from css --to scss actual.css>newlyCreated.scss

sass-convert --from css --to sass actual.css>newlyCreated.sass